# Mysql where column=id vs where column in (ids)

Tags: mysql

I was wondering why do we use

```
where column=id
```

vs

```
where column in (id)
```

I know that the first will only allow a single id while the second will allow multiple ids,  However why don't we always use in even for a single column search?

In other words why do we not always use "where column in (id)"?

Comment: Benchmark it! I'd be curious to see if there is any performance difference.

Comment: I imagine it's because of performance reasons. Imagine this: You're given a 'I want this ID'. The engine goes through every single row and checks, if the ID matches. Now, imagine the same for a list of items. For each row, it needs to iterate through the list and ask 'is it one of these'? And even if there's only one of them in there, it still needs to iterate through 'one'.

Comment: I actualy have a database api which always uses `IN (value)` in its getRecord function - so far there haven't been any issues with it. My guess is mysql will optimise it to `=` at some point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are essentially the same, so they are interchangeable. It is a personal preference which one to use.

Personally, I would use `=` when I know I will never check for more than one value. I would use `IN` if there's a good chance I will modify the query later to add new values to the list.

When performance isn't a concern, instead of `IN`, I sometimes use `REGEXP` as it more succinct, and requires less typing:

```
WHERE column REGEXP '^(value1|value2)$'
```

or

```
WHERE column REGEXP '[[:<:]](value1|value2)[[:>:]]'
```

Of course the less well known 'null-safe' equality operator `<=>`:

```
WHERE column <=> id
```

does not have an equivalent `IN` version.